# How can I automatically put same header, footer and layout to every pages generated by this PHP code?

Tags: php, html

Here is my code

```
<?php
$myFile = "hidata.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$counter = 1;
$page = 2;

while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
    if ( $counter > 10){
         file_put_contents( '/i', $page.".php", '<li>' . $theData . '</li>' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND  );
       if ($counter == 20){
               $counter=10;
               $page++;
       }
    }else{
    echo ('<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
   }
   $counter++;
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

This code automatically generates new .php pages everytime the `hidata.txt` reaches more than 10,20,30... lines of texts. I want every generated pages to automatically have same header, footer and layout. How can I do that in this code?

**Edit:** I tried it but not working

```
<?php
    $myFile = "hidata.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$counter = 1;
$page = 2;
$newpage = true;


while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
    if ( $counter > 10){
        if ($newpage) {
            file_put_contents(..... $header .....);
            $newpage = false;
        }
        file_put_contents( '/i', $page.".php", '<li>' . $theData . '</li>' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND  );
        if ($counter == 20){
            $counter=10;
            $page++;
            $newpage = true;

        }
    }else{
        echo ('<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
    }
    $counter++;
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

**Edit 2:** Here is my hidata.txt

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
```

and so on

And here is my header.php

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: Try with `file_put_contents( '/i', $page.".php", '<?php include header.php;?> <li>' . $theData . '</li>' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND ); `

Comment: @prasanth Not working. Not showing anything from header.php. Also the header should be placed above `<li>Data</li>`. Not beside it.

Comment: Why you are creating new.php pages??

Comment: @Huzaifa Umair Because I want each page to contain 10 lines of `<li>data</li>`

Answer (score 0):

[edit - sample code]

```
$page = 2;
$newpage = true;


while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
    if ( $counter > 10){
         if ($newpage) {
            file_put_contents(..... $header .....);
            $newpage = false;
            }
         file_put_contents( '/i', $page.".php", '<li>' . $theData . '</li>' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND  );
       if ($counter == 20){
               $counter=10;
               $page++;   
               $newpage = true;

       }
```

---

[original]

You could add code something like this:

```
if ( $counter > 10){  

 /********** YOUR CODE HERE *****/
  if (first putfor this page) {
      file_put_contents('/i',$page.".php",$header . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
/*******                  *****/  

     file_put_contents( '/i', $page.".php", '<li>' . $theData . '</li>' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND  );
```

Similary, append the "footer" when you `$page++;`. You'll have to check before the `fclose` that the final footer was written.

`$header` could be a string like `require_once("header.php")`, or the result of a `file_get_contents`, depending on what you need. Ditto the footer.

Comment: what is `first putfor this page`? Do I have to put something there?

Comment: What I mean is: before you `file_put_contents` of the first `<li>` to a new $page, you should `file_put_contents` the header.php (either by include or by content). It looks to me that $page.php will contain 10 `<li>` elements; I assume you want the header once and first. Therefore you wouldn't want it to execute every time you execute a `file_put_contents` inside the loop. Thus an `if` would be needed.  (ditto the footer, once and last). I could be misunderstanding your code.

Comment: No. You are not misunderstanding. I copied your lines and pasted in my code but it was not showing anything in the browser. Then I replaced the `if (first putfor this page)` to `if ( $counter > 10 )` and also added a variable `$header = require_once("header.php");` and it showed the header but the code stopped generating new pages. Only working in the main page.

Comment: I added a code snippet to the answer to illustrate my thinking. I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it but not working. Updated the code in the question you can see. Can you tell me where is wrong?

Comment: I don't know what means "not working". I can only present ideas, because I don't have  the text file, the header, nothing. Anything in the php error log? Maybe you need to "put" the whole header.php, not just the require. On the face of it, pages will not create valid html. Ah ha,  "require_once..." is _not_ the right approach since $page.php will not have php tags, so it's meaningless. And I don't see where `$header` is set in the new post of code. And you should not straight copy the sample `put_file_contents`, I just used the ... to save typing. That line has to give an error.

Comment: Sorry. I meant the page wasn't showing anything. I have updated my question again with whats on my `hidata.txt` and `header.php`.

Comment: Are you outputting errors?  Blank page usually means PHP errors.  Throw this at the top of your PHP page right under the opening php tag: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`

Comment: I didn't mean I wanted to see the files. I was trying to encourage you to troubleshoot "deeper" since you have all available information. The "pages" are not creating valid html, that could be the problem (you can't have `<li>` without `<ol>` or '<ul>` for example), it's certainly A problem. Track down errors. Compare what you are getting to the code you have written, line by line. Let the troubleshooting begin!